# Django- manytomany model relationships

Tags: django, many-to-many, relational-database

I'm still learning about how to setup up relational databases.  I'm trying to create a db that tracks universities, departments, and their programs.  My question is a relationship one.  Each university might have one or more departments.  This relationship should then be a many to many. Each department may have one or more programs, so I can see the relationship between the department and the programs being many to many.

The problem that I have is if I want to have a department that belongs to a university, I feel like I should use an intermediary to attach a program to that department.  But then, if I want to add another program to the same department, I would end up having two of the same departments belonging to the one university.  This doesn't seem right.

In other words:

```
class Department(models.Model):
    '''
    '''
    code = models.CharField(max_length=80,unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.description)


class Universities(models.Model):
    '''

    '''
    code = models.CharField(max_length=80,unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    departments = models.ManyToManyField(Department,through='UniversityHasDepartment')

class Program(models.Model):
    '''
    '''
    code = models.CharField(max_length=80,unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __unicode__(self):   
        return '{}'.format(self.description)

class UniversityHasDepartment(models.Model):
    university = models.ForeignKey(Universities)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department)
    program = models.ForeignKey(Program)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use foreign keys. (one to many relationships).

Each university can have multiple departments but a department can only have 1 university.
Each department can have multiple programs but a program can only have 1 department.

```
class University(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80,unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Department(models.Model):
    university = models.ForeignKey(University, related_name='departments')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80,unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Program(models.Model):
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, related_name='programs')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80,unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Comment: I agree with you, just an observation: the `related_name` seems a little bit confusing to me, I think it should be `related_name='university'`, `related_name='departament'` respectively, and in this way you can use `Program.objects.filter(departament='Mathematics')`. IMO its more intuitive than `Program.objects.filter(university='Mathematics')`.

Comment: I see what you mean.  But I would like to be able to compare programs across many departments.  For example, a many departments might have a microbiology program, though the required courses in each of those programs might be different.  That's why I thought to use a many to many relationship.  The same thing applies to departments.  Shouldn't each university's biology department be an instance of the same Department class, necessitating a many to many?